# How can I give a value to a static variable in a managed C++ class?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static, managed-c++

In VC++ CLR project I have a class temp. I am trying to set the static variable temp1 to 5.

I am getting a compilation error:

> Error 32  error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A0005FB) "public: static
> int temp::temp1" (?temp1@temp@@2HA)  C:\Users\user100\Documents\Visual
> Studio 2012\NewProject 32 bit\create min bars from data2\create min
> bars from data\create min bars from data5.obj
>
> Error  33  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int
> temp::temp1" (?temp1@temp@@2HA)  C:\Users\user100\Documents\Visual
> Studio 2012\NewProject 32 bit\create min bars from data2\create min
> bars from data\create min bars from data5.obj

How can I fix it?

```
class temp
{
    public:
    static int temp1;
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    temp::temp1 = 5;
}
```

Comment: `int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)` does not look like C++ to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define your static member variable:

```
class temp
{
    public:
        static int temp1;
};

int temp::temp1 = 0;

// Fixed main() ;)
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        temp::temp1 = 5;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: "initialize" is not the correct word.  I think "define" would be better. The *declaration* (inside `class`) tells the compiler that something exists, somewhere (so it can be compiled against). The *definition* (with scope-resolution operator `::`) tells the compiler where it exists (so it can be linked against).

Answer (score 6):

When declaring a static variable within a class, no memory is actually created.  You need a separate variable callout to actually make RAM for it.  That is what the compiler is telling you.

```
//Outside your class declaration:
int temp::temp1;
```